# How can I use \appendix with Beamer's ignorenonframetext option?

Tags: beamer, errors, hyperref, bugs

I am almost certain that the following used to work just fine. However, it certainly doesn't work any more.

I have workshop materials (based on UK TUG's) which use wrappers to input a common file containing the material for slides, handouts and notes. `ignorenonframetext` is used to avoid having the workshop exercises appear in the slides.

Last year, I started supplementing the handouts by adding appendices. This worked great. This also worked in November. It does not, alas, work now.

MNWE:

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{some frame}
some frame
\end{frame}

\appendix

\section{appendix}
some stuff
\end{document}
```

I first get lots and lots of messages saying

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\translate ' on input line 20.
```

This message is repeated numerous times, with exactly the same line number.

This is followed by numberous instances of the following message,

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\translate ' on input line 21.
```

with, again, the same line number.

After a while removing `\translate` on lines 20 and 21, TeX gives up.

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
<inserted text> 
                \<>-\translate 
l.21 

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

What has changed and what should be changing to avoid this problem?

I am compiling with pdfTeX. I get the same error with TeX, LuaTeX or XeTeX, however.

Comment: There had been a bug report about this: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/464

Comment: @samcarter Thanks. That's very helpful. I couldn't see a question here. I'm not quite sure I understand the bug discussion, though.

Comment: You're not the first one with this problem: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42562151#42562151 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug introduced in beamer version 3.44. For the moment this bug is fixed in the development version of beamer (and probably in release versions >= 3.50?), see the related bug report at https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/464

While using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/josephwright/beamer/master/base/beamerbasesection.sty the MWE compiles fine again.